# How to display variable data in verticaly in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

using Laravel 5.6 and in my application I have div box to show variable data. currently it is displaying horizontaly like this,
[div tag data showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSU24.png)

and this is My div tag,

```
<div style="border-style: solid; color: black; ">
                            <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>
                        {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($vehicule->created_at)->diffForHumans()}} 
                            {{$vehicule->provincename}}
                          {{$vehicule->milage}}
                          </div>
```

but I need showing this data as vertically in this div tag. how can I do this?

Comment: Can you show us how your generated html looks like?

Comment: what did you mean? I cant clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can use `display: flex` on the parent container to put the contents horizontally.Then wrap the variables in an unordered list `ul` and make them `li` elements.

Note that i wrapped the `ul` in a `div`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

/* Just for the demo */
ul { 
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://fillmurray.com/150/170"/>
  <div class="data-container">
    <ul>
      <li>Province name variable</li>
      <li>Milage variable</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad i could help! :)